# SSH Connection to ubuntu works on the internal network, but not from outside

Tags: openssh

**The other similar questions on ask ubuntu have not helped me resolve this issue.**

I have an ubuntu server that I can ssh onto no problems when I am on a computer on the local network, but when I try from outside I get

```
Permission denied (publickey)
```

I've created a new key pair and added the public key to authorized_keys.

I've made sure that authorized keys has the correct permissions set (0600)

The port forwarding on the router seems to be setup correctly as I can see my attempts to connect in /var/log/auth.log

```
Oct 26 16:37:59 ubuntu sshd[1804]: Connection closed by xx.xx.xx.xx [preauth]
```

This is what I get with the -vvv option

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/mike/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/mike/.ssh/config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: /home/mike/.ssh/config line 145: Applying options for beansprout.1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Hostname has changed; re-reading configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/mike/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/mike/.ssh/config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to xx.xx.xx.xx [xx.xx.xx.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/mike/.ssh/beansprout_live" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/mike/.ssh/beansprout_live type 1
debug1: identity file /home/mike/.ssh/beansprout_live-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "xx.xx.xx.xx" from file "/home/mike/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/mike/.ssh/known_hosts:24
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "xx.xx.xx.xx" from file "/home/mike/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/mike/.ssh/known_hosts:24
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host 'xx.xx.xx.xx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/mike/.ssh/known_hosts:24
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/mike/.ssh/beansprout_live (0x555f8eacc7c0), explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: 
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/mike/.ssh/beansprout_live
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey)
```

I also ran tcpdump, this is what I got when I tried to ssh in

```
frank@ubuntu:~/.ssh$ sudo tcpdump -i any src host xx.xx.xx.xx -vvv
tcpdump: listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 65535 bytes
16:45:31.390406 IP (tos 0x4, ttl 58, id 5782, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    S0106bc4dfb2cb3c3.vc.shawcable.net.33168 > 192.168.1.100.ssh: Flags [S], cksum 0x2529 (correct), seq 1124079693, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 5246683 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:45:31.438365 IP (tos 0x4, ttl 58, id 5783, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    S0106bc4dfb2cb3c3.vc.shawcable.net.33168 > 192.168.1.100.ssh: Flags [.], cksum 0xef7b (correct), seq 1124079694, ack 2925922470, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 5246693 ecr 138876], length 0
16:45:31.438403 IP (tos 0x4, ttl 58, id 5784, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 95)
    S0106bc4dfb2cb3c3.vc.shawcable.net.33168 > 192.168.1.100.ssh: Flags [P.], cksum 0x91f4 (correct), seq 0:43, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 5246693 ecr 138876], length 43
16:45:31.500729 IP (tos 0x4, ttl 58, id 5785, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    S0106bc4dfb2cb3c3.vc.shawcable.net.33168 > 192.168.1.100.ssh: Flags [.], cksum 0xef08 (correct), seq 43, ack 44, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 5246708 ecr 138890], length 0
16:45:31.501685 IP (tos 0x4, ttl 58, id 5786, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    S0106bc4dfb2cb3c3.vc.shawcable.net.33168 > 192.168.1.100.ssh: Flags [.], cksum 0xcc1c (correct), seq 43:1491, ack 44, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 5246708 ecr 138890], length 1448
16:45:31.502110 IP (tos 0x4, ttl 58, id 5787, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 572)
    S0106bc4dfb2cb3c3.vc.shawcable.net.33168 > 192.168.1.100.ssh: Flags [P.], cksum 0x6aec (correct), seq 1491:2011, ack 44, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 5246708 ecr 138890], length 520
16:45:31.530287 IP (tos 0x4, ttl 58, id 5788, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    S0106bc4dfb2cb3c3.vc.shawcable.net.33168 > 192.168.1.100.ssh: Flags [.], cksum 0xe18e (correct), seq 2011, ack 1492, win 251, options [nop,nop,TS val 5246719 ecr 138891], length 0
16:45:31.530301 IP (tos 0x4, ttl 58, id 5789, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    S0106bc4dfb2cb3c3.vc.shawcable.net.33168 > 192.168.1.100.ssh: Flags [.], cksum 0xe0a3 (correct), seq 2011, ack 1692, win 274, options [nop,nop,TS val 5246719 ecr 138903], length 0
16:45:31.540611 IP (tos 0x4, ttl 58, id 5790, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 100)
    S0106bc4dfb2cb3c3.vc.shawcable.net.33168 > 192.168.1.100.ssh: Flags [P.], cksum 0xb828 (correct), seq 2011:2059, ack 1692, win 274, options [nop,nop,TS val 5246721 ecr 138904], length 48
16:45:31.581987 IP (tos 0x4, ttl 58, id 5791, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 68)
    S0106bc4dfb2cb3c3.vc.shawcable.net.33168 > 192.168.1.100.ssh: Flags [P.], cksum 0xd4f3 (correct), seq 2059:2075, ack 1972, win 296, options [nop,nop,TS val 5246732 ecr 138915], length 16
16:45:31.656372 IP (tos 0x4, ttl 58, id 5792, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 104)
    S0106bc4dfb2cb3c3.vc.shawcable.net.33168 > 192.168.1.100.ssh: Flags [P.], cksum 0x0736 (correct), seq 2075:2127, ack 1972, win 296, options [nop,nop,TS val 5246750 ecr 138936], length 52
16:45:31.688538 IP (tos 0x4, ttl 58, id 5793, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 120)
    S0106bc4dfb2cb3c3.vc.shawcable.net.33168 > 192.168.1.100.ssh: Flags [P.], cksum 0xb402 (correct), seq 2127:2195, ack 2024, win 296, options [nop,nop,TS val 5246758 ecr 138942], length 68
16:45:31.764659 IP (tos 0x4, ttl 58, id 5794, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 424)
    S0106bc4dfb2cb3c3.vc.shawcable.net.33168 > 192.168.1.100.ssh: Flags [P.], cksum 0x5f1e (correct), seq 2195:2567, ack 2076, win 296, options [nop,nop,TS val 5246777 ecr 138962], length 372
16:45:31.800705 IP (tos 0x4, ttl 58, id 5795, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    S0106bc4dfb2cb3c3.vc.shawcable.net.33168 > 192.168.1.100.ssh: Flags [F.], cksum 0xdc27 (correct), seq 2567, ack 2128, win 296, options [nop,nop,TS val 5246785 ecr 138970], length 0
16:45:31.858424 IP (tos 0x4, ttl 58, id 5796, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    S0106bc4dfb2cb3c3.vc.shawcable.net.33168 > 192.168.1.100.ssh: Flags [.], cksum 0xdc09 (correct), seq 2568, ack 2129, win 296, options [nop,nop,TS val 5246800 ecr 138984], length 0
```

Where else could I look to try and figure out what is setup wrong?

Thanks

edit:

ssh config settings

```
Host *
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no

Host beansprout.1
    HostName xx.xx.xx.xx
    User frank
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/beansprout_live
```

Comment: What are the contents of `/home/mike/.ssh/config`? are different options being applied when the external hostname/address is invoked?

Comment: It's hard to compare, internally I only have a windows machine, so connect with PuTTY. On my external (linux) machine the config is fairly standard. I'll edit the question with what I have set in there. (The 2 machines have their own key pairs btw)